# EF Core: Column with ValueGeneratedOnAdd trows "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column..."

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, aws-lambda, entity-framework-core

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 application that uses Entity Framework 6.2. This app creates some records in MS SQL server.

I have to process this records in AWS lambda function. For this purpose, I created c# .NET Core v2.0 lambda function. There I generate models from existed DB as described in the next article - [Getting Started with EF Core on ASP.NET Core with an Existing Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db).

Generated models look like:

```
public partial class Request
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }   
    public Result Result { get; set; }
}
public partial class Result
{
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public Request Entity { get; set; }
}
```

And OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Request>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.EntityId);
        entity.ToTable("Request", "mySchema");
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Result>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.EntityId);
        entity.ToTable("Result", "mySchema");
        entity.HasIndex(e => e.EntityId).HasName("IX_EntityId");
        entity.Property(e => e.EntityId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entity.HasOne(d => d.Entity)
            .WithOne(p => p.Result)
            .HasForeignKey<Result>(d => d.EntityId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_mySchema.Result_mySchema.Request_EntityId");
    });
}
```

In the lambda function, I am processing a request and  setting result:

```
using (var db = new DataContext(connection))
{
    var request = db.Request.First();    
    request.Result = new Result();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

On the save operation I got the exception:

*Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Result' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.*

I checked different way to solve this issue. But there are already set `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` function in model creating method.

Also, I tried to add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to Result.EntityId  - without any success.

What did I miss in my implementation?

Comment: Can you show the existing `Request` table you are trying to map? There is something wrong with PK and FK configuration, but can't say exactly w/o seeing the table columns and constraints.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Result` table.

Comment: Hey RredCat, where you able to resolve this problem? I have same one...

Comment: @Borbea, Yes. But I don't work anymore at this company and I don't have access to the source code and solution.
As I remember, it was a pretty simple solution.

Comment: @rredCat I solved my problem using ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate because I was receiving above error on record update. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to initialize request.Result with new Result() which has no values.  That may cause this error.

Comment: I don't think it is an issue. I tried to set 'Entity' it didn't help. EntityId should be autogenerated.